# Submit Form using Onchange without clicking any key

Tags: php, html

Made this simple form that interfaces with a Database, but when I enter a Barcode, I have to press a keyboard key, I've tried many JS commands, but I can't make it work automatically

```
<body>
<?php
if(!isset($_GET["barcode"]))
{
    <form name="form1" action="barcodeindex.php">
    <input type="text" onChange="this.form.submit()">
}
else
{
    $code=$_GET["barcode"];
    echo "<h1>The Barcode is $code</h1>";
}
```

Comment: you can't just inject html into php like that. And where's the closing `</form>` tag?

Comment: there's also missing code here and the origin of the GET array

Answer (score -1):

OnChange triggers only when you change focus outside text field, not on every key pressed in text field. If you need to submit every time key is pressed add event listener for OnKeyPress.

Suggestion: Make submit in separate function, and use JQuery to assign events. Place them in separate .js file and make apache headers not to cache it. Or add yourscript.js?ver1.1 as name where you include it. Event assign must be in JQuery onDocumentReady function.

Also you may want use ajax, since working without submit button, so everything saved once it changed.